# Plugin for Maven that Exports non-project files of choosing to a RAR/compressed filetype

Tags: maven-2, maven, compression, rar

Here's what I need to accomplish:

Take some files, and create a Zip/Rar/Tar file while running the maven package command.

With the maven-rar-plugin I can only create a compressed file containing all of the contents needed to run the program.

Are there any sort of third part, or maven plugins that I may have missed?  I know this can be done by adding/calling a python script from my pom.xml, but would like to do it all with maven.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) will help here?